# Terminal rows are misaligned when using TMUX over SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, tmux

I updated Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 last month, and have noticed some odd behaviour when using TMUX over SSH ever since. (This issue does not occur on the console directly.) To access this shell I'm using OpenSSH within Cygwin, which resides inside a [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) wrapper. The terminal size is 132x43.

I think what might be going on is TMUX doesn't know the correct height of the terminal window or one of the parent containers. Is this something I need to define somewhere?

Firstly when I open TMUX the only odd thing is that the status bar row is positioned 1 row too high:

[image: View of TMUX when initially opened]

If I don't do anything for a while the status bar starts to duplicate:

[image: View of TMUX after doing nothing for a few minutes]

I can scroll up to see the working directory again, but with the text input position 1 row too low:

[image: Scroll up a bit]

If I press CTRL+L to clear the screen the status bar disappears, and I have to scroll down to get it.

Next, if I press CTRL+, to rename the window, each key I type creates a new status bar row:

[image: Renaming the TMUX window]

I've also tested this on a Debian Stretch target, and the issue doesn't occur there, so I'm inclined to think that the issue is specific to my Ubuntu 18.04 VM. Here's the same situation but with a Debian Stretch host:

[image: Same of the above, but towards a Debian Stretch host]

Comment: Interestingly this could be a ConsoleZ wrapper issue. Using the Cygterm64 wrapper TMUX is fine on Ubuntu. Posted my issue to ConsoleZ too just in case it is: https://github.com/cbucher/console/issues/503

Comment: Update: Not a ConsoleZ fault as that is not designed to emulate a Unix compatible console. (It's only a Windows console wrapper as intended.)

Comment: Additional note: Today I updated some of my Debian 9 VPSes to Debian 10, and this issue has now appeared there too. I guess a newer version of a package has caused this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for this here: https://github.com/cbucher/console/issues/175

Essentially wrapping the TMUX session within a Screen session wraps the screen pretty well. You **do not** need to install Screen in Cygwin.

ConsoleZ -> SSH -> Screen -> TMUX

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and managed to resolve it with the advice from this blog post: http://blog.bigsmoke.us/2018/06/15/garbled-screen-in-tmux-on-ubuntu-18.04-in-konsole

Add the following to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -as terminal-overrides ',*:indn@'
```

The blog talks about a bug in Konsole but for me the issue happened in other terminals too, including over SSH, and this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the blog link, I checked the issue on Github too. Unfortunately this made no difference.

Comment: :( Sorry to hear that